# Explain why this code doesn't work

Tags: java

I have two classes that refer to each other:

```
class B{
  A obj;
  B(A obj){
    this.obj=obj;
  }
  void display(){
    System.out.println(obj.data);//using data member of A class
  }
}

class A{
  int data=10;

  A(){
   B b =new B(new A());  //  THIS LINE GENERATES AN ERROR
   b.display();
  }
  public static void main(String args[]){
   A a=new A();
  }
}
```

If I change the offending line to read

```
   B b =new B(this);
```

then it works.  I think that the two lines do the same thing.  Why does one work and not the other?

Also, the compiler error from the first version reads

```
A.<init><A.java:15>
```

What does this mean?

Comment: what is your question exactly? You think that this should result in a compile / runtime error? This is valid code

Comment: new A() always creates a new object, a new reference to the class and as well calls the constructor, in this case this loops infinite, instead if you pass "this" - it references to current object. To simplify -new A() - creating a new object , this not creating a new object using current object

Comment: Best edit ever @Nathaniel !

Answer (score 13):

By calling `new A()` inside `A()` you produce an infinite loop invoking the constructor. This is the error.

I'll explain to you in more detail:
When you pass `this` into the `new B(...)` constructor, you are passing a *reference* to the newly constructed object of class `A` whose constructor you are currently inside of. This is OK, because it doesn't cause any further action beyond constructing a new `B`.

When you replace it with `new A()`, you must first produce a new instance of class `A`. This is not a problem yet. The problem is that when you get inside constructor `A() { ... }`,  everything begins again: you'll get to the line `B b =new B(new A());` and will again invoked the `A` constructor which will end up back at this line again and so until you receive a `StackOverflowError`.

Comment: Not exactly an ideal introduction to recursion, amirite?